# including libaries in Maven Proguard plugin

Tags: maven, proguard

i'm trying to refer to my libary jars through Proguard Maven Plugin , how can i include 'em ? normaly i point at my libaries in the configuration file , it worked when i used to obfuscate using DOS . here's my Maven proguard config

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <options>
                    <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                </options>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <injar>{project.build.directory}/proj-SOC.jar</injar>
                <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-obfuscated.jar</outjar>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <proguardInclude>src/main/ressources/projSOC-obfuscation-config.conf</proguardInclude>
                <libs>
                <lib>lib/rt.jar</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: maven proguard plugin automaticaly adds libraries to proguard based on project dependencies .